# how to delete all directories in a folder

Tags: linux, directory, delete

I want to delete all directories in the `download` folder.

```
/content/download/documents/
/content/download/music/
/content/download/videos/
/content/download/pictures/
```

I have tried removing them using `rm` but it's not working.

```
rm -rf '/content/download/*/'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wildcard `*` doesn't expand inside quotes (either within single quote nor double-quote), so you need write that out of quotes:

```
rm -rf '/content/download/'*/
```

however quotes are necessary only when the path or filename contains whitespaces/newline or some other characters that are special to the shell to prevent interpreting them by the shell.

With the trailing `/`, `*/` will expand to all files of type directory *after symlink resolution*, so will also include symlinks to directories. The expansion will be something like `/content/download/dirlink/` for those. What happens for those depends on the `rm` implementation. With the ones typically found on Linux-based systems, that will remove the *contents* (recursively) of the target directory of the symlink, but not the symlink nor the directory itself.

Also note that it won't remove hidden directories.

---

If your shell is bash, you can read more in its manual, in particular:

- [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)
- [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html)
- [Shell Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html)

Comment: In fact, no quotation marks are needed unless the path name contains spaces or characters special to the shell. Here, they could be omitted.

Comment: I have looked some man pages for `rm` but I didn't find the above tactic. Could u link to some that explains in depth

Comment: @Mujtaba that's about shell not the `rm` command, pleas see links added into answer

Answer (score 0):

```
find ~/Downloads -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | xargs rm -rf
```

This solution does not depend on the specific shell (`bash`, `zsh`, etc.) you are using.

Comment: But it needs a `find` implementation that supports those non-standard `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth` extensions and would fail if filenames contain whitespace or `'` or `"` or ``\`` (with possibly dire consequences). POSIXly, and more reliably, you'd do `find ~/Downloads/. ! -name . -prune -type d -exec rm -rf {} +`